# A working version of checkinstall

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

## What's I'm doing:

I'm trying to build a deb package of a compiled version of qt.

## Where I'm at:

```
$ wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.0/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0.tar.xz
$ tar -xf qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0.tar.xz ~/src/qt
$ cd ~/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/sim-qt --opensource --confirm-license --skip qtcharts --skip qtvirtualkeyboard --skip qtdatavis3d --silent --nomake examples --nomake tests
$ make
```

If I run `sudo make install`, everything installs fine, but I need a .deb package so that other people in my organization can also install the same binaries without the need to re-compile.

## The problematic step:

I've read that the tool I should use is `checkinstall`. I tried `checkinstall` with a simple helloworld example and things seemed to be fine.  This is the perfect situation and is exactly what I was expecting.  However, when I try to install this Qt project, I get errors like so:

```
$ checkinstall -D --install=no --pkgname=sim-qt --pkgversion=5.10.0 --pkgrelease=0 --pkglicense=LGPL --nodoc
...
/home/stew/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/stew/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/include/QtGui/QDragLeaveEvent /opt/sim-qt/include/QtGui/QDragLeaveEvent
Error copying /home/stew/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/include/QtGui/QDragLeaveEvent to /opt/sim-qt/include/QtGui/QDragLeaveEvent: Cannot create /opt/sim-qt/include/QtGui/QDragLeaveEvent for output
Makefile:69204: recipe for target 'install_class_headers' failed
make[3]: [install_class_headers] Error 3 (ignored)
...
```

## Identifying the problem:

It sounds like this is an [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/78455) with checkinstall which has existed since at least 2007 (that was the oldest report I could find).

## Trying a work-around:

Some people recommended to use `--fstrans=no`, and when I do that I see that now I can at least install folders, but the files all fail to deploy:

```
$ checkinstall -D --install=no --pkgname=sim-qt --pkgversion=5.10.0 --pkgrelease=0 --pkglicense=LGPL --nodoc --fstrans=no
...
/home/stew/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/stew/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qttranslations/translations/qtscript_en.qm /opt/sim-qt/translations/qtscript_en.qm
Error copying /home/stew/src/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qttranslations/translations/qtscript_en.qm to /opt/sim-qt/translations/qtscript_en.qm: Cannot create /opt/sim-qt/translations/qtscript_en.qm for output
Makefile:2841: recipe for target 'install_translations' failed
make[2]: [install_translations] Error 3 (ignored)
...
```

## What's next:

This is where everyone seems to stop.  If `checkinstall` had a cripling bug for 11 years that renders it totally useless, then I would imagine that it wouldn't exist anymore.  But it does.  So I'm missing the work-around that people seem to be finding.  Otherwise, I'm confused on what to do next.

How do people package deb files?

I found this [tutorial for ubuntu](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html).  But it assumes that you are using Canonical's bzr for a version control system and uses the VCS as part of its operation?  I'm not planning to push this package to Ubuntu and so I don't really understand why the instructions also include `bzr commit...` and stuff.

I also found this [tutorial for debain](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/first.en.html#workflow).  I like it because it doesn't rely on some strange version control system automatically generating stuff.  But it also seems to assume that I have pre-debianized tar.gz source archives and I intend to submit the packages to debian.  It also assumes that I don't want to add any parameters to `./configure` which is false.  I've tried adding common-line parameters to `debian/rules` in the `override_dh_auto_configure` section but I can't tell if it's working as everything seems to be failing about 10000 lines before I get my command prompt back.

Here's [another tutorial on the subject](https://coderwall.com/p/urkybq/how-to-create-debian-package-from-source) but this one requires you to have a gpg key, something I am expecting my apt repository to handle when I reprepro the deb package to the apt repo. When running through this solution I also had problems with the build failing.  Because it prints out tens of thousands of lines, I can't tell where/why it is failing.  Only that `dh_auto_clean: make -j10 clean returned exit code 2`

Basically, I wanted something exactly like checkinstall, just without a crippling bug that prevents it from actually working.  What I am getting is the broken checkinstall, and three alternative methods, all of which will require me to invest my entire week on troubleshooting (I've already spent several days).  Is there a way to fix checkinstall, or to have a 2-3 command solution to get from my "make" solution to a .deb solution?

Normally I use cpack to make my deb packages, but since this source uses autoconf, I am a bit stuck with how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `checkinstall` was actually working.  The problem was the project that I was trying to install.  checkinstall (like dh_make) sets `DESTDIR=some/temp/location` during the `make install` step.

This project uses `qmake`, and the Makefile generated by `qmake` does not understand the `DESTDIR` directive.  Instead `INSTALL_ROOT` was required.

I ended up using `dh_make` and hard-coded `override_dh_auto_install` to set `INSTALL_ROOT` manually instead of `DESTDIR`.

The `dh_make` command generates rules files needed to configure, build, install, and package the project.

After running `dh_make`, edit the newly generated `debian/rules` file to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@  --with autotools-dev --parallel
override_dh_auto_configure:
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/sim-qt --opensource --confirm-license --skip=qtcharts --skip=qtvirtualkeyboard --skip=qtdatavis3d --skip=qtwebengine --silent --nomake=examples --nomake=tests QMAKE_ARGS+=INSTALL_ROOL=/opt/sim-qt QMAKE_ARGS+=DESTDIR=

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install -Smakefile -- INSTALL_ROOT=$(CURDIR)/debian/sim-qt/
```

Then configure, build and package with one command:

```
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -nc -j10 -us -uc
```